# Restore database, moving ldf and mdf to the default location

Tags: restore

When I try

```
RESTORE DATABASE [foo] FROM DISK = 'C:\foo.bak'
```

the restoration procedure will try to put the dat and log in a location that was available on the system where the backup was done (like G:\MSSQLDB), but there is no such location on my computer.

I therefore need to MOVE that locations, but all I care about is that there is a valid location. I have no use of specifying a certain location.

Can I move to the location where all normally ldfs/mdfs go? I tried to just end the command with `WITH MOVE`, but without any luck.

Comment: You can use `with move` clause to move it to drive you like, should not be a problem. What is the error you are getting

Comment: I do not care where mdf and ldf goes at all. I want them to go anywhere.

Comment: 'MOVE' is not a recognized RESTORE option

Answer (score 2):

This is a long way around, I didn't remember that `SERVERPROPERTY` can be used to return the paths and realise that those parts of `RESTORE DATABASE` syntax could accept variables. See [the answer by Charlieface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/310365/61) for a simpler method.

---

There is no way of asking for a default to be used: without `MOVE` directives files go where they were when backed up, and with them you have to specify a location.

You could pickup the locations from information in `sys.database_files` in `master` assuming that database is in the location(s) you want to use. The full path will be in the `physical_name` column, if you have logs and data in different places (as is generally recommended) you can differentiate by the values `ROWS` or `LOG` in `type_desc`. From there you'll need to make a new path by taking the filename off the full path found in `physical_name` and replacing it with a filename for the newly restoring DB, and construct the `RESTORE` command as a string to be run via `EXEC (@SQLInVariable)` as you can't use variables in the `MOVE` directive of `RESTORE`.

Also, if you don't know the names of the files in the DB you are restoring you'll need to detect them too by capturing the output of `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` because you'll need those names for the `MOVE` directive too.

So what I think you want *is* technically possible, but probably more hassle than it is worth unless you are restoring DBs this way a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the information you need from the system [`SERVERPROPERTY` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments), then add a `MOVE` parameter to the `RESTORE`

```
DECLARE @mdfLocation nvarchar(256) = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS nvarchar(200)) + 'YourDb.mdf';
DECLARE @mdf sysname = 'LogicalMdfName';

DECLARE @ldfLocation nvarchar(256) = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') AS nvarchar(200)) + 'YourDb.ldf';
DECLARE @ldf sysname = 'LogicalLdfName';

DECLARE @dbName sysname = 'foo';
DECLARE @bak nvarchar(256) = 'C:\foo.bak';

RESTORE DATABASE @dbName
FROM DISK = @bak
WITH
  MOVE @mdf TO @mdfLocation,
  MOVE @ldf TO @ldfLocation;
```

Note how every part of `RESTORE` can be parameterized, it does *not* need dynamic SQL.

You can even pick up the logical filenames using `RESTORE FILELISTONLY`, although that requires `INSERT EXEC` to get the info in pure T-SQL.

If you don't even know how many files you are restoring then you will need dynamic SQL for the number of `MOVE` parameters. You can still pass through the actual filenames as parameters.